# display specific data from sql database in php with more than row of data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a newbie and developing php laundry service.

im using SESSION for the login,

Im having trouble when a username add a laundry ticket 2 times, so it will create 2 ticket_id, for example, 1001 and 1002 in table TICKET. they are both different order, under same username.

so when I want to display for example, ticket_id,

i do

```
SELECT ticket_id FROM TICKET WHERE ticket_username=$username
```

problem is it will show both of ticket id 1001 and 1002 since they are from same username.

im stuck help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point you would want to be able to retrieve all orders by a customer or do you not want a user to be able to create 2 orders at the same time?
Anyway, if you only want the first order just use `limit`

```
SELECT ticket_id FROM TICKET WHERE ticket_username=$username LIMIT 1;
```

But I think you need to be clear about whether two orders can be created and how you're going to prevent if if they can't.

Comment: yes i want user be able to create 2 orders..  where user will be able to view a list of ticket they have/submitted. I'm still looking for  a way to do this. or is it impossible?

Comment: It's possible. You'll want to return a list of all orders for a customer, as you're currently doing, and use that to output a list of orders on the screen. These will be links/buttons/whatever, each one with the id of the corresponding order. You use that id to select where id = ?id to get back one specific order

Comment: I am able to list the order from the same username as for now.. however i lost u on "these will be links/buttons....."

the problem that I'm actually having is that after the data is stored into the database, I want to display the only 1 row of data which the user just keyed in,  so if I do

select  * from ticket where ticket_username=$username

it will list all the previously entered ticket order.. 

the logic that i want to try is

select * from ticket where ticket_username=$username and ticket_id=(the ticket_id that just stored by auto increment just now)

if u get me haha

Comment: I do but for the user to be able to select which order they want to view they need to be able to pick it from a list. So your first step is to show ALL orders for that customer so they can select one and get that record returned. But if you want to show the order they just entered and saved but you don't have the ID you can do this query: select * from ticket where ticket_username=$username order by id desc limit 1. That will return the last order in the database for that username

Comment: i'll give it a try on that one.. 1 more question sir, is it possible if I wanted to 

SELECT ticket_id FROM ticket WHERE ticket_username=$username ORDER BY ticket_id desc limit 1??

since user dont have the id yet, but it is stored in database. like u said, i want to show the order they just entered right after they key in..

Comment: Yes, that query gets the all orders for that user, sorts them by ID in descending order i.e. highest first and then returns the first result. You can also use SELECT MAX(id) from ticket WHERE ticket_username = $username to achieve the same thing.